Quarkus 2 to Quarkus 3 migration problem with SpringData @Query and @Hints
Migrating a project from Quarkus 2 to Quarkus 3, in a JpaRepository I have this method
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = AvailableHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = AvailableHints.HINT_READ_ONLY, value = "true")
})
@Query(value = "SELECT obj FROM Object o JOIN o.children child WHERE child.xi.id = :xiId")
Stream<Object> streamObjectsByXiId(@Param("xId) Long xId);

which gives me a compilation error because org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints in quarkus-spring-data-jpa-api still uses javax.pesistence.QueryHint instead of jakarta.persistence.QueryHint.
Any workaround or ideas of how to fix it? Thanks a lot

This will be fixed soon
